# How to distribute values of a list inside nested dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to distribute the values from lists to some keys inside nested dictionaries. The issue I am having is most likely a loop problem, as I was able to input the values in the correct keys, but they are all repeated.

I've tried converting it to a list of dictionaries with no luck, but ideally, it should remain as a dictionary in the end

```
dictionaries_list = {}
factors = {"var": [],
            "card": [],
            "val": []}


potential = [['0.5 0.5'], ['0.2 0.8'], ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']]

for node in names:
  dictionaries_list[node] = factors.copy()

for dicts in dictionaries_list.copy():
  for prob in potential:  
    dictionaries_list.get(dicts)["val"] = prob

print(dictionaries_list)
```

The expected result is :

```
{'A': {'var': [], 'card': [], 'val':['0.5 0.5']}, 
'C': {'var': [], 'card': [], 'val': ['0.2 0.8']}, 
'B': {'var': [], 'card':[], 'val': ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']}}
```

I am getting:

```
{'A': {'var': [], 'card': [], 'val': ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']}, 
'C': {'var': [], 'card': [], 'val': ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']}, 
'B': {'var': [], 'card':[], 'val': ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate them parallel. You can use `zip` in python. Please Try:

```py
dictionaries_list = {}
factors = {"var": [],
            "card": [],
            "val": []}


potential = [['0.5 0.5'], ['0.2 0.8'], ['0.9 0.1', '0.8 0.2', '0.3 0.7', '0.1 0.9']]

for node in names:
  dictionaries_list[node] = factors.copy()

for dicts, prob in zip(dictionaries_list.copy(), potential):
    dictionaries_list.get(dicts)["val"] = prob

print(dictionaries_list)
```